# Sort with Insert statement

Tags: sql

I'm calculating a linear regression in SQL and need to preserve the Sort order in the #regression_data table.

I'm creating a time series regression and the row_number() is creating the count for X values.  The regression needs to maintain the proper sort order to function properly.

The following code works properly when I don't insert into a temp table because I have the ability to sort.  Even if I use don't create a Temp Table I don't believe I sort within a derived query.

if object_id('tempdb..#regression_data') is not null begin drop table #regression_data end

```
Select CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as INT) 'x', CAST([Pax] as INT) 'y', *

--into #regression_data
from #TBB_Temp
```

´   Order by [Depart Year],[Booking Year], [Sorter]

Comment: Tag your question with the databse you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is to move the sort to the `row_number()`:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Depart Year], [Booking Year], [Sorter])) as x,
       CAST([Pax] as INT) as y,
       t.*
--into #regression_data
from #TBB_Temp t;
```

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so the outer `order by` does very little.

Another method adds an identity column instead:

```
select identity(int) as x,
       CAST([Pax] as INT) as y,
       t.*
--into #regression_data
from #TBB_Temp t
order by [Depart Year], [Booking Year], [Sorter];
```

The one exception to `order by` being meaningless for an `insert` is that `identity` respects the ordering.

Note that for both these methods, you *have to use `order by`* when querying the table:

```
select rd.*
from #regression_data rd
order by x;
```

See above note on tables and unordered sets.